# How can I change server in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

> **My project requirement is to use another server than tomcat? How can
> we change embedded server from spring boot application?**

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

Answer (score 7):

You have to exclude tomcat from starter dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and now you need to include new server as a dependency i.e.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need to update `pom.xml`, add the dependency for `spring-boot-starter-jetty`. Also, you will need to `exclude` default added `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In gradle,

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
 
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Gradle way

     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
     modules {
      module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat") {
          replacedBy("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty", "Use Jetty instead of Tomcat")
      }
     }

# Gradle Another Way

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot',
        module: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `Embedded Web Servers` in `Spring-Boot` is `Tomcat`, but you can easily change it to others.

First of all, you need to **exclude** tomcat:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then you can add your desired embedded web server:

```
<!-- Jetty Embedded Web Server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<!-- Undertow Embedded Web Server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```