# Is there a way to change the server from the embedded server

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am just starting with spring boot. I wanted to change my server from embedded server to spring boot starter jetty. How do I go about it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054114/how-can-i-change-server-in-spring-boot-application) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can replace the Embedded Tomcat with any other servers by using the Starter dependencies. You can use spring-boot-starter-jetty  or spring-boot-starter-undertow as a dependency for each project as you need.